# How do I regenerate imagecache thumbnails in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, thumbnails

My thumbnails images are all missing from my hosting account causing my gallery images to show broken as shown in screenshot.

[image: Broken Images]

I have tried creating a new gallery and uploading images to the gallery hoping it would rebuild the thumbnails however this has failed as well. So somehow image cache is not creating the thumbnails anymore and removed what was there completely.

Answer (score 1):

Images in specific image style are generated when ever image in that style (thumbnail if you like) is displayed on page, but file doesn't exist. If that fails this is what I would check first:

- First check file permissions. Can PHP  write to `/sites/default/files`
- Do you have original image. Maybe thumb can't be generated because original image is missing or it's not allowed to PHP to read it (file permissions again).
- Maybe some PHP graphic library is not installed (correctly) so generation process just fails.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it - however it does not explain why all my thumbnail images are all missing, I viewed the /sites/default/files/imagecache/somename-thumbnails folder as root and it was empty. The permissions issue explains why it no longer creates thumbnails in that folder that make sense, but what of the others that should be there, hence why I need to know if the thumbnails can be regenerated or will I have to re-upload all those images again to regenerate them?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I found that imagemagick was set to the incorrect binary path for convert and after updating the thumbnails appear to be loading. I made changes in /admin/settings/imageapi/config/imageapi_imagemagick The suggestions @milanG gave was almost correct but it wasn't that the graphic library that was missing, it was just that the site couldn't find it. The path had been set to the default which was likely just a result of the move.